# Detect statistical anomalies

Tags: data-mining

I've read these SO questions and this is not duplicate of them

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306785/best-way-to-statistically-detect-anomalies-in-data
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531374/statistical-calculations
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221984/algorithms-for-spotting-anomalies-spikes-in-traffic-data

---

I've collected statistical data about people

Data hierarchy is like this:

- Region

  - Street

    - Building number
    - Entrance number

      - [Statistical package]

[Statistical package] contains (in this example)

- floor (stock) number
- UUID (defining flat)
- Religion
- Appearance of toilete

**What algorithm or procedure should I use** to discover anomalies like:
or **What statistical programming framework should I use?**
(including what is best underlaying technology - like SQL or Document oriented DB, interpreted or compiled language, and so on)

1-a :: Only one floor (of every floors in building) has no toilets
1-b :: One flat (UUID) has no toilet although all other flats in entrance/building has at least on
2-a :: There is one flat claiming Religion X although whole Region has Religions Y and Z
2-b :: There is one building claiming Religion X although whole Region has Religions Y and Z

But this is only example on limited number of Statistical package attributes, I should find many types of anomalies on around 15 attributes in every Statistical package

Note: this question is not about how should I find anomalies for provided examples, those examples are just illustrative, I'm looking for common solution/algorithm

Thanks beforehand for any response

Comment: If you want your question to be migrated, flag it for moderator attention and write it into the text field. (This is preferable to reposting it.)

Comment: I second that: I recommend moving to stats.SE.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a relational database that has [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) features, arranging the data in a [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) like so:

```
Fact: UUID
Dimensions: Region, Street, Building number, Entrance number, Floor (stock) number, Religion, Appearance of toilete
```

Then I would make a view over it with a large number of features, average religion per region, per building, appearance of toilet per floor/building ... etc.

```
Vector: UUID, Dimensions: Region, Street ..., Features: average per X, max per Y ... etc
```

Now I have a big vector space to witch I can easily apply common anomaly detection algorithms.

**For example** let's say that training `data size (m) < 10 * number of features (n)` and we are on a reasonable powered computer to apply multivariate Gaussian probability density estimation.

For our training vectors

\begin{align*}
{x^{(i)}} \in \mathbb{R}^n, i \in 1..m
\end{align*}

Our probability function is:
\begin{align*}
p(x, \mu, \Sigma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}|\Sigma|^{n/2}}exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\bigg)
\end{align*}

So we need to fit the parameters:

\begin{align*}
\mu=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mx^{(i)}
\space , \space
\Sigma=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m(x^{(i)}-\mu)(x^{(i)}-\mu)^T
\end{align*}

Now, that we can compute $p(x, \mu, \Sigma)$ we can flag a fact as anomalous if:

\begin{align*}
p(x, \mu, \Sigma)<\epsilon
\end{align*}

By varying $\epsilon$ we will enlarge/restrict our anomalous facts class, and for really small values of $\epsilon$ we will find the most far away outliers (assuming there are any).

All there is to do now is vary $\epsilon$ and analyze different results.

Comment: oh, that's amazing nice. I'm going to test it, but before I find out, you deserve at least upvote ;-) Thanks